# A more pythonic way to write this expression?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm supposed to take a list of words and sort it, except I need to group all Strings that begin with 'x' first.

Here's what I got:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []

for word in words:
  list_1.append(word) if word[0] == 'x' else list_2.append(word)

return sorted(list_1) + sorted(list_2)
```

But I have a feeling there is a much more elegant way to do this...

**EDIT**

Example:
`['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']` yields `['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
>>> words = ['xoo', 'dsd', 'xdd']
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda x: (x[0] != 'x', x))
['xdd', 'xoo', 'dsd']
```

Explanation: the key function returns a pair (tuple). The first element is `False` or `True`, depending on whether the first char in the string is `'x'`. `False` sorts before `True`, so strings starting with `'x'` will be first in the sorted output. The second element in the tuple will be used to compare two elements that are the same in the first element, so all the strings starting with `'x'` will be sorted amongst themselves, and all the strings not starting with `'x'` will be sorted amongst themselves.

Comment: Don't quite get why this works. Is True always greater that x?

Comment: @Helper: it compares tuples, first element of which is either `False` or `True`. This way all tuples having `False` as a first element preceding all tuples that have `True` as the first element. When the first elements are the same, comparison is done based on the second element, which is too say in this case is standard alphabetical sort.

Comment: `(0,0) < (0,1) < (1,0) < (1,1)` is True.

Comment: In other words, the default collation order is the same for all sequences--strings, tuples, lists and strings.  It's a useful property that Python programmers should understand.

Comment: +1 Didn't saw the (). Wow, really nice answer. Still I took Glenn's answer as accepted because while this maybe faster, I could understand his code without any thinking, while it took me some time to explain why your's worked (this may be due to the fact that I'm a Python noob ^^).

Comment: sorted(words,key=lambda x:'0'+x if x[0]=='x' else x) ....I came down to post this but your method is much better..thanks

Comment: @Rafi: that's ascii zero character, there are 48 characters that compare less, try your code with `words = '/abc', 'xabc'`

Comment: sorted(words,key=lambda x:'\0'+x if x[0]=='x' else x)....So is this correct? If not can you please point me to a table or something for comparison of how sorted() compares strings

Comment: @Rafi: yes, it would work as you'd expect. You could just consult ascii table to see the order of characters.

Comment: I would use `not x.startswith('x')` instead of `x[0] != 'x'`.  I feel uneasy assuming that none of the words will be `''`.

Answer (score 9):

First: stop saying "pythonic" when you mean "clean".  It's just a cheesy buzzword.

Don't use terniary expressions like that; it's meant to be used as part of an expression, not as flow control.  This is cleaner:

```
for word in words:
    if word[0] == 'x':
        list_1.append(word)
    else:
        list_2.append(word)
```

You can improve it a bit more--using terniary expressions like this is fine:

```
for word in words:
    target = list_1 if word[0] == 'x' else list_2
    target.append(word)
```

If `words` is a container and not an iterator, you could use:

```
list_1 = [word for word in words if word[0] == 'x']
list_2 = [word for word in words if word[0] != 'x']
```

Finally, we can scrap the whole thing, and instead use two sorts:

```
result = sorted(words)
result = sorted(result, key=lambda word: word[0] != 'x')
```

which first sorts normally, then uses the stable property of Python sorts to move words beginning with "x" to the front without otherwise changing the ordering.

Comment: By the way, although it lacks in explanation, @SilentGhost's version is faster and cleaner as final code.  (I prefer my answer because I think it's more instructional, but of course I'm biased.)

Comment: On the word "pythonic": there's some interesting discussion in the comments here: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201011/pythonic.html

Comment: i think the presented use of the ternary expression is perfectly valid. one could even write `( list_1 if word[ 0 ] == 'x' else list_2 ).append( word )` which is clearer.

Comment: pythonic != clean; pythonic > clean

Comment: @flow: Valid does not imply clean or natural.  Note that putting spaces around function call arguments will make it hard for people to take your opinion of clean code seriously.

Comment: i find `f( x )` much clearer than `f(x)`. the more arguments you have, the more helpful spaces between arguments and parentheses become. but of course, tastes may differ.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is ANY different from the one proposed in the question.

Comment: @drozzy: Then I suggest actually reading the answer; half of the text of the answer explains exactly what's different, and why.

Answer (score 6):

```
words = ['xoo', 'dsd', 'xdd']
list1 = [word for word in words if word[0] == 'x']
list2 = [word for word in words if word[0] != 'x']
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that `sorted` was added in Python 2.4 .  If you would like a shorter version which is a bit cleaner and somewhat more backwards compatible you can alternatively use the `.sort()` functionality directly off of `list`.  **It should also be noted that empty strings will throw an exception when using `x[0]` style array indexing syntax in this case (as many examples have).** [`.startswith()` should be used instead, as is properly used in Tony Veijalainen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077249/a-more-pythonic-way-to-write-this-expression/4079610#4079610).

```
>>> words = ['mix', 'xyz', '', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
>>> words.sort(key=lambda x: (not x.startswith('x'), x))
>>> words
['xanadu', 'xyz', '', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

The only disadvantage is that you're mutating the given object.  This may be remedied by slicing the list beforehand.

```
>>> words = ['mix', 'xyz', '', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
>>> new_words = words[:]
>>> new_words.sort(key=lambda x: (not x.startswith('x'), x))
>>> new_words
['xanadu', 'xyz', '', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
>>> words
['mix', 'xyz', '', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
words = ['xoo', 'dsd', 'xdd']
list1=filter(lambda word:word[0]=='x',words)
list2=filter(lambda word:word[0]!='x',words)
```

Answer (score 2):

To resend variation SilenGhosts code (feel free to copy, SilentGhost) as code not command prompt log

```
notinorder = ['mix', 'xyz', '', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']
print sorted(notinorder, key = lambda x: (not x.startswith('x'), x))
```

Comment: I find that the `startswith` and `endswith` are most useful when testing against a set of conditions (they accept tuple) or when the prefix's length is not predefined.

Comment: Benefit is that I can deal with '' without fix like x or x[0] != 'x', performance I do not know, but readability counts... Your solution is kind of automatic zip/unzip for sorting by the interpreter, neat stuff! Could generalize... Thanks for reminding about tuple point, I have seen tuple used with one string operation, but forgot which!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = ['abc', 'xyz', 'bcd', 'xabc']
>>> y = [ele for ele in x if ele.startswith('x')]
>>> y
['xyz', 'xabc']
>>> z = [ele for ele in x if not ele.startswith('x')]
>>> z
['abc', 'bcd']
```

Answer (score 0):

More along the lines of your original solution:

```
l1=[]
l2=[]
for w in sorted(words):
    (l1 if w[0] == 'x' else l2).append(w)
l1.extend(l2)
return l1
```